# вывод double без округления

Tags: java, double

Это приложение - простой калькулятор, мне нужно при делении задать TextView результат, и так чтобы это было без округления, в моём случае округление идёт до целых чисел

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnPlus;
    Button btnMinus;
    Button btnMultiply;
    Button btnShare;
    TextView tvOut;
    EditText etFirst;
    EditText etSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnMinus = findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnPlus = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        btnMultiply = findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
        btnShare = findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        tvOut = findViewById(R.id.tvOut);
        etFirst = findViewById(R.id.etFirst);
        etSecond = findViewById(R.id.etSecond);

        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnShare.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public int getFirstNumber() {
        int first;
        first = Integer.parseInt(etFirst.getText().toString());
        return first;
    }

    public int getSecondNumber() {
        int second;
        second = Integer.parseInt(etSecond.getText().toString());
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int out;
        int first = getFirstNumber();
        int second = getSecondNumber();
        String outS;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.btnPlus):
                out = first + second;
                outS = Integer.toString(out);
                tvOut.setText(outS);
                break;
            case (R.id.btnMinus):
                out = first - second;
                outS = Integer.toString(out);
                tvOut.setText(outS);
                break;
            case (R.id.btnMultiply):
                out = first*second;
                outS = Integer.toString(out);
                tvOut.setText(outS);
                break;
            case(R.id.btnShare):
                double outD;
                outD = first/second;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(outD));
                tvOut.setText(Double.toString(outD));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Калькулятор с целочисленными аргументами, вот и результат целочисленный =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из за того, что у обоих переменных тип `int` происходит целочисленное деление.
Нужно хотя бы одну привести к вещественном типу:

```
outD = (double)first/second;
```

Тогда и результат будет вещественным.

Comment: Будет вещественным результат, но не сами вычисления

Comment: Не согласен. Выражение `first / second` вернет целочисленный результат, а потом делается `cast` для сохранения в переменную `double`. Но это все теория, а компилятор сделает так как настроено.

Comment: Причем тут компилятор? Операция `cast` имеет самый низкий приоритет, соответственно вычислнения будут целочисленные, а результат в `double`

Comment: Ну например, если бы `first = 4` и `second = 1` были константы то вычисление произвел бы сам компилятор, а фактически выражение свелось бы к `outD = 5`, так что я бы не стал спорить как происходит вычисление примитивов, это решает не программист. А теория простая, если оба оператора деления целочисленные то и результат целочисленный, если хоть один вещественный то и результат вещественный.

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar, у `cast` выше приоритет. http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php